# How do I remove a quill stem?

Tags: road-bike, stem, restoration

(I recently got an old Favorit road bike (made in Czechoslovakia) and started restoring it. In order to give the frame a new coat of paint, I need to strip it down from everything.)
I'm stuck with the quill stem. I'm not sure how to remove it because it's impossible to just pull it out and there are no screws holding it. There is this long screw about 7 inches long that I took out but it doesnt seem to affect anyway the quill stem. So how can I remove it (if it's even possible)?

Comment: Loosen, but do not remove, the long bolt down the middle, then tap the head of the bolt with a hammer.

Comment: There's your answer.

Comment: Well, if you took out the 7 inch long screw, and you can't move the stem, then it's possible that it's rusted and fused to the fork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the bolt. You need to turn it out only for a half inch, then easily strike it with a hammer. (Don't make a strong strike, to not drive in the quill stem if it rusted!) Usually it will be enough, Yet it can be a little rusted, so hitting with your hand on the handles will help. Sometimes it's very rusted, so you will need to use some oil to deal with it. Very rarely it rusted so much, that nothing will help.